What is the name of the lady with the white blouse?
Three ladies meet: Mrs. Red, Mrs. White, and Mrs. Green. One of the ladies notices, "Strange, one of us is wearing a red blouse, another is wearing a white one, and the third is wearing a green one." "That's really amazing," says the lady with the red blouse, "because none of us is wearing the blouse that matches her name." "That's true," adds Mrs. White.
What is the name of the lady with the white blouse?
It is an easy one, but still interesting. You may consider it as appetizer for Who is sitting at the banker's left?


 There are two feasible answers satisfying the first two sentences.


 1: Mrs. White is wearing a red blouse, Mrs. Green is wearing a white one, and Mrs. Red is wearing a green one.


 2: Mrs. Green is wearing a red blouse, Mrs. Red is wearing a white one, and Mrs. White is wearing a green one.


 According to the last sentence, Mrs. White adds to the observation by the lady with the red blouse, so they are distinct persons. (This interpretation is a bit loose, but otherwise I see no clues to prefer one of the possibilities.) So, Mrs. White in not wearing the red blouse, thus there remains only the second possibility.


It’s

 Mrs. Red.

My reasoning process:

 Given information:
 There are three ladies, each wearing a different colored blouse, and the color of their blouses does not match their names.

 The lady in the red blouse spoke to Mrs. White, which means Mrs. White cannot be wearing the red blouse. Therefore, Mrs. White must be wearing the green blouse to be consistent with the given information. Since the lady in the red blouse cannot be named Mrs. Red, she must be Mrs. Green. Finally, the lady in the white blouse must be named Mrs. Red.

